# Firebase: Search by email without letting users see all users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Imagine I have a database:

```
emails
 - test1@test.com: userID1
 - test2@test.com: userID2
 - test3@test.com: userID3
```

How can i create a Firebase rule that a user can search to see if an email address exists and subsequently get the userID, but can't view the entire list?

e.g

```
/path emails {

   read() { true }, // But will let user view all emails signed up
   write() { writeIfNotExists() }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for a user to search data that they are not allowed to read. Either a user can read data, in which case they can search and retrieve it, or they can't read data, in which case they can neither retrieve nor search it.

If you want to implement such a use-case, your best bet is to implement a search API as a [HTTP endpoint in Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).